# Churban Bayis Sheini Not on Tisha B'Av?

Tags: history, calendar, tisha-bav, churban-destruction

I recently heard that the destruction of the 2nd Temple was not actually on Tisha B'av, the date of the destruction of the 1st Temple, but that it was pretty close, so the rabbis had it commemorated on the same day.
Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: You are liekly thinking of the 1st Temple

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9724&st=&pgnum=57

Answer (score 1):

this is a discussion in the gemara in [taanith 29b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=10&daf=29&format=text),

Comment: Not elaborating on your answer defeats the purpose of answering

Comment: @Nafkamina It doesn't defeat the purpose entirely, because it provides new information (namely, that the gemara discusses when the First Temple was destroyed, and a reference for the discussion). Still, this type of comment is less than adequate as an answer.